# Laravel Model relation error how to fix it?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, database

I have two model : Barang and Ruangan

at migration barang :

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateBarangTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('barang', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('nama');
            $table->string('spesifikasi');
            $table->foreignId('id_ruangan');
            $table->string('kondisi');
            $table->integer('jumlah');
            $table->string('sumber_dana');
            $table->string('jenis');
            $table->string('keterangan');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        
        Schema::table('barang', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('id_ruangan')->references('id')->on('ruangan');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('barang');
    }
}
```

at migration ruangan

```
    <?php use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration; 
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
class CreateRuangansTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ruangan', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('nama_ruangan');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('ruangans');
    }
}
```

Here My model Barang

```
 <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Barang extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $table = "barang" ;

    public function ruangan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Ruangan::class);
    }
}
```

when i call this on tinker

```
$bar = new Barang
$bar = Barang::first()
$bar->ruangan->nama_ruangan
```

its return null ,

even though in each table on database I have added some dummy data

i have spend 3hours to solve it and not find the answer , i have rollback the migration , i create it twice and still not solved please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you are using a foreign key outside the [naming convention](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-defining-the-inverse-of-the-relationship) of laravel, you have to pass the custom foreign key name as the second argument of the relationship definition.

```
public function ruangan()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Ruangan::class, 'id_ruangan');
}
```

and then you can access `$bar->ruangan->nama_ruangan;` to get `nama_ruangan` from Ruangan model.

Comment: Thank you very much the answers from NoobDev and zahid hasan emon had to be combined and finally my program ran as I wanted

after i add relation in both model and use

return $this->belongsTo(Room::class, 'id_room');

finally i can call
$bar->room

and return value

App\Models\Room {#3648
     ids: 1,
     room_name: "Administrative room",
     created_at: "2021-12-09 17:24:25",
     updated_at: "2021-12-09 17:24:25",

Comment: how to accept two answers at this question?

Comment: it's not mandatory to use the hasMany relationship to access `$bar->ruangan->nama_ruangan`

Comment: thank you very much for helping me, I will remember your help
I very appreciate what you did.,

previously
sorry, because seeing your reputation is already great so I will choose the answer from NoobDev so that he too can grow great like you,

but actually you two did it and I really appreciate that ,

Comment: you have to choose the right answer actually so that it can help future so users.

Comment: Ok thankyou very much i will consider it

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the relation on Ruangan model ?

Example:

```
  public function barang()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Barang::class);
    }
```

And by the way first returns the first item inside a collection

Comment: I just added , I changed the relation to hasMany()

i keep getting null value

Comment: Thank you very much the answers from NoobDev and zahid hasan emon had to be combined and finally my program ran as I wanted

after i add relation in both model and use

return $this->belongsTo(Room::class, 'id_room');

finally i can call
$bar->room

and return value

App\Models\Room {#3648
     ids: 1,
     room_name: "Administrative room",
     created_at: "2021-12-09 17:24:25",
     updated_at: "2021-12-09 17:24:25",